# Is it ok to upload encrypted pdf file on arXiv?

Tags: academic-life, arxiv

Is it ok to upload a pdf file of my paper with "edit with permission of author-password encryption" on arXiv? Is it good? And also please answer, can your paper show "submitted" status and **then** put "on hold"?

Comment: It’s not ok even to upload an unencrypted PDF. I believe that nowadays you are required to upload the source files of your paper.

Comment: You know PDF edit passwords are easily broken, right? There is a billion tools to remove them even online.

Comment: This would definitely be in the category of things you shouldn't do, even if you can.

Comment: See "red herrings" https://arxiv.org/help/faq/whytex

Comment: Why is this getting downvotes? It's a bad idea, but this does not make it a bad question.

Comment: "On hold" comes after "submitted", *if* it is put on hold.

Comment: @DanRomik PDF option **is** there!

Comment: @FedericoPoloni hmm I got your point.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist you mean I should not encrypt file or I should not submit pdf files? why?

Comment: Friends, talking about plagiarism and copying, no format can prevent it. So why to choose TeX over pdf?

Comment: @user151413 Thanks

Comment: What is "edit with permission of author-password encryption"?

Comment: @Dumb The link provided by Anonumous Physicist provides ample of reasons why to use tex.  Did you read it?

Comment: It's a password encryption method for pdfs, it's not really rigorous term though.

Comment: @user151413 yes, but that does not help in stopping people copying the content of paper, right?

Comment: @Dumb You ask " So why to choose TeX over pdf?". Under the link provided, there are ample of reasons listed.

Comment: By the way, you should focus on ***one*** question. You have two completely unrelated questions.

Comment: @user151413 Sure!

Comment: The "submit as PDF" option on the arXiv might be there, but if you use it without providing good reason (e.g., your paper is written in Word or troff, or your LaTeX packages clash with arXiv's in an unfixable way), they might still block your submission. (I've even seen a PDF submission getting removed a few days after appearing, in a rare deviation from arXiv's "what's posted stays forever" principle. In that case, though, the author had it coming by writing their paper in LaTeX, then compiling, then saving the result as bitmap images and gluing them back together as PDF...)